# Book series for kids with boy and stones that went on belt

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel, magical-items

I remember reading a book series during elementary school that had a boy who found a magic stone that went into a belt. I think that he kept finding more of them to keep them from who/whatever the antagonist was. I do remember there being a lot of ravens. They showed up all the time when things were getting tense, and maybe they were an alternate form of the antagonist. I know he was attacked by them at least one time.

It was a series, fairly long, and something you would read around 4th-5th grade. It was written in English. This was somewhere between 15-20 years ago, and I don't think that the books were new at the time I read them.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another possibility is *[The Dark is Rising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence)* series by Susan Cooper. There are five books in total:

- Over Sea, Under Stone
- The Dark is Rising
- Greenwich
- The Grey King
- Silver on the Tree

Part of the story involves collecting a set of six Signs, which are circles, quartered, made of different materials. The main character in most of the series, Will Stanton, is followed and attacked at least once by ravens.

Books 1 and 3 focus on Barney, Jane, and Simon Drew who are drawn into the struggle of the Light against the Dark by their great-uncle Merriman Lyon.

Bran, a Welsh boy, is also an important character, as is his dog, Cafall.

Comment: I do believe this was the series!

Comment: _When the Dark comes rising, Six shall turn it back;  Three from the circle, Three from the track.  Wood, Bronze, Iron; Water Fire Stone; Five will return and One go alone._ / _Iron for the birthday, Bronze carried long; Wood from the burning, Stone out of song; Fire in the candle-ring, Water from the thaw; Six Signs the circle, and the Grail gone before._ / _Fire on the mountain shall find the Harp of Gold; Used to wake the Sleepers, Oldest of the Old; Power from the Greenwitch, lost beneath the Sea; All shall find the Light at last, Silver on the Tree._

Comment: - From memory (may be small mistakes), the often-repeated poem Will Stanton followed in the second book, _The Dark is Rising_.

Answer (score 8):

Could this be the [Deltora Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(series)) books?

(bolding mine)

> The first series of *Deltora Quest* follows the journeys of Lief, the son of a humble blacksmith [in disguise], who, on his sixteenth birthday, sets out to fulfill his fathers quest to restore the Belt of Deltora. Joining Lief is an ex-palace guard named Barda. Along the way they meet with Jasmine: a wild girl from the Forests of Silence, who has long, black hair and emerald eyes. She can speak to trees and has two pets: a raven named Kree and a small, gray, furry creature called Filli. **Their quest is to find the seven gems of the fabled Belt of Deltora: the topaz, the ruby, the opal, the lapis lazuli, the emerald, the amethyst, and the diamond**. The gems each have a special power and are hidden in dangerous locations around Deltora. The three friends must face numerous perils to reach them. Once the Belt is complete and the proper descendant of the first King of Deltora, Adin, wears the belt, the evil tyranny of the Shadow Lord will be forced back to the Shadowlands. The books in this series are *The Forests of Silence*, *The Lake of Tears*, *City of the Rats*, *The Shifting Sands*, *Dread Mountain*, *The Maze of the Beast*, *The Valley of the Lost*, and *Return to Del*.

They came out in 2000, which fits your time-frame (although it pains me to admit that 2000 was almost 20 years ago). It involves a belt with gems on it. There is a pet raven although I've found no reference to ravens attacking them.

Comment: I don't think we have an accepted answer for the book series, but we do have about three for the anime adaptation.  :-D

Comment: If this is the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.