# Book in which there are creatures with large gems embedded into them

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read these series of books (never completed them though) that were several volumes (at least 4 or 5, possibly more).

I read these when I was 10-ish, so around 2007. The books were much older but I can't remember the author or publication date.

All I remember from them is that, the cover art for each book was a different creature with a colored gem with them (more like embedded into them, and the colors of the gems were different each time).
I am sure there was a giant toad with a gem on its head and I believe there was a snake as well.

I think the protagonist was searching and killing these things as they were evil but I can't remember.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I've closed the question as a duplicate, but that doesn't mean it's a bad question, just one we've answered before. You can still garner upvotes and comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Deltora Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(book_series))* by Emily Rodda

[image: Image showing the first 12 covers]

> The first series of Deltora Quest follows the journeys of Lief, the son of a humble blacksmith [in disguise], who, on his sixteenth birthday, sets out to fulfil his father's quest to restore the Belt of Deltora. Joining Lief is an ex-palace guard named Barda. Along the way they meet with Jasmine: a wild girl from the Forests of Silence, who has long, brown hair and green eyes. She can speak to trees and has two pets: a raven named Kree and a small, grey, furry creature called Filli. Their quest is to find the seven gems of the fabled Belt of Deltora: the topaz, the ruby, the opal, the lapis lazuli, the emerald, the amethyst, and the diamond. The gems each have a special power and are hidden in dangerous locations around Deltora. The three friends must face numerous perils to reach them. Once the Belt is complete and the proper descendant of the first King of Deltora, Adin, wears the belt, the evil tyranny of the Shadow Lord will be forced back to the Shadowlands. The books in this series are The Forests of Silence, The Lake of Tears, City of the Rats, The Shifting Sands, Dread Mountain, The Maze of the Beast, The Valley of the Lost, and Return to Del.

The snake ([Reeah](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Reeah)) and toad ([Gellick](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Gellick)) are in the 3rd and 5th  books, *[City of the Rats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_the_Rats)* and *[Dread Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dread_Mountain)*. I've never actually read the series myself, but I've provided this as an answer for both the [book series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191120/book-series-for-kids-with-boy-and-stones-that-went-on-belt/191122#191122) and the [anime](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186382/cartoon-network-show-monster-hunting-dark-theme-monsters-looked-to-be-done-by?noredirect=1&lq=1), which was also shown on Cartoon Network.

Comment: Repeatedly identified; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192661/book-about-three-companions-forced-to-solve-puzzles-to-find-gems/192689#192689